# R's lm showing strange behaviour with ordered factors

Tags: r, lm

When I plug in an ordered factor into the `lm` function results are unexpected (to me).

Surely there is a good explanation for this...

```
# Generate some data
# parameters
n = 20L
set.seed(11L)

# Ordered factor
t <- factor(sample(c(1L, 2L), size = n, replace = TRUE),
       label = c("Low", "High"), 
       ordered = TRUE)
t
 [1] Low  Low  High Low  Low  High Low  Low  High Low  Low  Low  High
[14] High High High Low  Low  Low  Low 
Levels: Low < High

# not ordered factor, keep reference level as High
tno <- factor(t , ordered = FALSE)
tno <- relevel(tno, ref = "High")
tno
 [1] Low  Low  High Low  Low  High Low  Low  High Low  Low  Low  High
[14] High High High Low  Low  Low  Low 
Levels: High Low

# A simple indicator variable
ti <- t == "Low"
ti
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[12]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

# Some dependent variable
y <- 10*rnorm(n)

# Run three regression
# Observe ordered factor is not giving the correct results
lm(y ~ t)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ t)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          t.L  
    -3.6082       0.8038

lm(y ~ tno)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ tno)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       tnoLow  
     -3.040       -1.137 

lm(y ~ ti)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ti)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       tiTRUE  
     -3.040       -1.137  


# Confirm correct intercept
mean(y[t == "High"])
[1] -3.039771
# Just rounding difference...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this

```
rest<- lm(y ~ t)
restno <- lm(y ~ tno)
resti <- lm(y ~ ti)

rest$fitted.values
restno$fitted.values
resti$fitted.values

rest$xlevels
restno$xlevels
resti$xlevels

rest$contrasts
restno$contrasts
resti$contrasts
```

What you will see is, first, that the fitted values are exactly the same for all three models.  So the model for ordered is not "wrong."

Second, you will see that the levels are different. In fact, only tno has levels. The others do not since you are treating them as though they are numeric, which you can do since this is a dichotomous variable. You'll also see that the factor is a string while the other two are not.

Third, you will see that tno and ti use "contr.treatment" while t uses "contr.poly"  which makes sense for an ordinal variable.

If you run this

```
restno_poly<- lm(y ~ tno, contrasts = list(tno = "contr.poly"))
restno_poly
```

You'll get

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ tno, contrasts = list(tno = "contr.poly"))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        tno.L  
    -3.6082      -0.8038
```

Likewise

```
rest_treatment<- lm(y ~ t, contrasts = list(t = "contr.treatment"))
```

Similarly gives the results you were expecting.

[This page explains more.](http://faculty.nps.edu/sebuttre/home/R/contrasts.html)